# How do I calculate conditional probability in R?

Tags: r, probability

I'd like to make a conditional probability table in R. I have a dataset that looks like this -

```
actions outcome
15  0
1   0
0   0
0   0
52  1
23  1
43  1
55  0
31  0
13  1
42  1
0   1
2   1
2   0
4   0
6   1
0   0
123 0
543 1
32  1
21  0
43  1
```

I want to make a table that lists the probability that someone will be outcome == 1 based on their number of actions. Something like this --

```
count of actions    probability of outcome given count of actions
0   0%
1   2%
2   2%
3   2%
4   3%
5   3.5%
6   4%
7   10%
8   10%
9   12%
10  15%
11  19%
12  20%
13  30%
14  54%
15  56%
16  60%
17  63%
18  68%
19  78%
20  95%
```

I tried to install prob() but I got an error message when I tried to install it. Am I missing the package or do I need to do the math myself?

Comment: Which package did you try to install? You should be specific about which package it was and include the error message you got.

Comment: Isn't this just `prop.table(table(df))` where `df` is your original dataset as a dataframe?

Comment: How did you obtain the your output? The logic/reasoning behind it? From the table above, what do you expect to get?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how you get the expected output from the sample data; I assume you're showing only a subset of the original data.

Unless I misunderstood your question, this should be a simple matter of `prop.table(table(...))`.

```
# Your sample data
df <- read.table(text  =
    "actions outcome
15  0
1   0
0   0
0   0
52  1
23  1
43  1
55  0
31  0
13  1
42  1
0   1
2   1
2   0
4   0
6   1
0   0
123 0
543 1
32  1
21  0
43  1", header = T)

# Fraction of outcome = 0 and outcome = 1 per action
prop.table(table(df));
#   outcome
#actions          0          1
#    0   0.13636364 0.04545455
#    1   0.04545455 0.00000000
#    2   0.04545455 0.04545455
#    4   0.04545455 0.00000000
#    6   0.00000000 0.04545455
#    13  0.00000000 0.04545455
#    15  0.04545455 0.00000000
#    21  0.04545455 0.00000000
#    23  0.00000000 0.04545455
#    31  0.04545455 0.00000000
#    32  0.00000000 0.04545455
#    42  0.00000000 0.04545455
#    43  0.00000000 0.09090909
#    52  0.00000000 0.04545455
#    55  0.04545455 0.00000000
#    123 0.04545455 0.00000000
#    543 0.00000000 0.04545455
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second part of the question about prob(), that requires the package `deal`. This was easily found by googling searching "prob() r" - I recommend google searching the function and R if you get the error message: `Error in prob() : could not find function "prob"`

Of note there is another package that contains prob(), called `prob`. I cannot install `prob`, as it is not available for R version 3.4.3.

For working out probability, I refer you to Mauritis' answer of `prop.table(table(...)).` I agree with him that I'm not sure how you obtained your expected output.